# How to set current time to edittext box in android without using time picker?

Tags: android, time

Can any one tell me how to set the current time in edittext box in android with out using Time-picker.

```
edt_time=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_time);
Time t = new Time();
java.text.Time tf =  android.text.format.Time.getCurrentTimezone(getApplicationContext());
edt_time.setText(tf.format(t));
```

Suggestions please.

Thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: Have you tried anything

Comment: @vinoth plz visit my question again

Comment: yes , by hard coding :D

Comment: @freak but my above code is showing error on the line 3

Comment: @prabu Please paste the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int mSeconds = c.get(Calendar.SECONDS);

EditText edt_time=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_time);
edt_time.setText(mHour +":"+ mMinute +:+ mSeconds);
```

Similarly you can also get year, month,day etc.

The above code must work but anyway try this.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String currentTime = sdf.format(new Date());
EditText edt_time=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_time);
edt_time.setText(currentTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); // current time in miliseconds, conver it however you want
```

then put in editText,

```
editText.setText(String.valueOf(time));
```